# Extracting data from a text file while searching through directories recursively

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt

I have several directories all containing a separate log file that I need to pull certain text from. An example of this would be log.txt contains information = 1, I need to pull all data after the =. I cannot use powershell or any other language. I've never scripted in batch before so I'm not sure where to start. Currently I can search for the directories containing this log file using the following:

```
dir /s log.txt > C:\saveLog.txt
```

Comment: Are all the files named the same (Log.txt)?  Is the information to search for always the same (information = 1)?

Comment: Yes all the files are named the same and have the same information layout inside of them.

Comment: Ok... I will post later when I have time if no one else does first.

Comment: I look forward to reading it RGuggisberg!

Answer (score 0):

You can do a nested for loop, cycling through the files in the outer loop, and looking for the information line in the log file in the inner loop:

```
@echo off

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /s log.txt') do (
  for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%j in (%%~si) do (
    set _var=%%j
    set _var=!_var: =!
    if defined _var (
      if /i "!_var!"=="information" (
        echo Filename: %%i; Information: %%k
      )
    )
  )
)

endlocal
```

This reports the log filename (with its path) and the information after the `=` sign in each file.  You can change the `echo` line as needed to report what you want to report.

FYI - The inner for loop splits each line of the log.txt file into two parts.  The first part is the text to the left of the `=` sign and is accessed via `%%j`.  The second part is the text to the right of the `=` sign and is accessed via `%%k`.  This is accomplished by adding `/f "tokens=1* delims=="` to the for loop command.

### Edit 1

- Changed the inner for loop to use short filenames, so that spaces in a path won't break the loop.
- Changed the `%%j` variable to a real variable so we can do character substitution and eliminate the space before the `=` sign (if one exists).  This keeps `%%k` as the content after the `=` sign.
- Changed `if` compare statement to be case-insensitive.

Comment: `information = 1` will break the for loop unless you include a space in the delims.  Making the test case insensitive is also a good idea to make it more bulletproof - The OP may have been slack when specifying the text.  Double quoting the `(%%i)` will also allow the OP to search for long filenames and paths.

Comment: Thanks James L.  One problem with using `(%%~si)` is that it isn't reliable and can return unusable results.  It's better to use `(' type "%%i" ')`

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=1,3 delims=:=" %%a in ('findstr /S /C:"information = " log.txt') do (
   echo Filename: %%a; Information: %%b
)
```